# In boost::asio, why are there no socket member functions for read/write?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I working on a client/server application using boost asio, specifically `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` to connect and transfer data. Right now I am using `boost::asio::async_read` to recive a certain amount of bytes. Until now, in all cases I know how many bytes I want to receive, before calling my handler. Therefore I don't see a reason to use the sockets meber function `read_some`. But I wonder why there is no "async_read" member function of `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` but only the free one.

So my question is: Are there conceptual or technical reasons why there is a `read_some` member function but no `read`member function, or did "Boost just forgot to implement it" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the streaming interfaces in Asio provide both `read_some` and `async_read_some` moethods.  This is true for the TCP sockets, SSL streams, and Serial ports.  The implementation of `read`, `read_until`, and their async cousins all have the same implementations, based on using the `read_some` method.  The `read` function is written as a generic template, that can use the `read_some` method on its first argument to perform the call as you requested.

There are some C++ advocates that recommend using non-friend non-member functions whenever possible, so as to minimize the changes when a class implementation changes.  `read_some` is the interface, and `read` is just a wrapper that adds blocking in the case of partial reads for a variety of different sources.

Comment: Thanks, I see the point. Nevertheless I find it somewhat confusing, to have the one as a member function but the other not...

Answer (score 3):

As Dave S says, you will find these as external helper functions in boost\boost\asio\read.hpp

If you look at [the boost 1.52 asio examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html), the [blocking_tcp_echo_client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_client.cpp) and [blocking_tcp_echo_server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp) examples use the blocking form of the `write()`. The example  uses `read_some()` because it does not pre-know the size ... however the write function is completely analogous to your read question and also exists as a helper `write.hpp` in the same place as `read.hpp`.

Basically:

```
 tcp::socket s(io_service);
 char buff[LENGTH];
 boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(buff, LENGTH));
 boost::asio::read(s, boost::asio::buffer(buff, LENGTH));
```